# Select data in one row from multiply rows from different tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

earlier I needed help with this using MSSQL, but now I have to use MySQL on other machine.
 I have tables:

```
----------    ----------    ----------
| offers |    |  bids  |    | users  |
----------    ----------    ----------
id            id            id
....          offer_id      first_name
....          user_id       last_name
              ....          .....
```

Now I need to each offer id assign user last and first name where

```
offers.id = bids.offers_id and bids.user_id = users.id
```

Example:

```
     offers                   bids                   users
------------------    ----------------------     ----------------
|id| ...| ....|       |id| offer_id| user_id|    |id| first_name| last_name|
------------------    -----------------------     --------------------------
|1 | ...|.....|       |1 |    1    |    2   |    | 2| Peter     | Jackson  |
|2 | ...|.....|       |2 |    1    |    3   |    | 3| Adam      | Black    |
                      |3 |    1    |    6   |    | 4| Roy       | Wright   |
                      |4 |    2    |    5   |    | 5| Eva       | Cekovsky |
                      |5 |    2    |    7   |    | 6| Martin    | Tyson    |
                                                 | 7| Vera      | Vornel   |
```

And the output should be like this

```
  offer_id                   full_name
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   1      |    Peter Jackson, Adam Black, Martin Tyson      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   2      |    Eva Cekowsky, Vera Vornel                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can easily connect last with first name using `CONCAT` and do it if every data was in same table, but this,I can't figure it out. Tried to use GROUP_CONCAT (as there is no STUFF in MySQL) but without much success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the three tables first nconcactenate the two columns and  pass this expression in `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT  b.offer_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name)) as Full_name
FROM    offers a
        INNER JOIN bids b
            ON a.id = b.offer_id
        INNER JOIN users c
            ON b.user_id = c.id
GROUP   BY b.offer_id
```

Comment: That was fast,thank you, just entered a few corrections. Line 2: GROUP_CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS Full_name    .... and line 4: removed doubled 'bids' word